# Match statement using multiple conditions

Tags: r

Consider the following code:

```
list <- c("apple", "pear", "orange")
match("apple", list)
```

This returns `1`.

Now suppose I want to return the index of an element if some other element is missing. For example:

```
match(c("apple", "banana"), list)
```

would return

`1  NA`

I want to return the index only if the element exists. So it should just return `1`. Is there a "match exist" statement in R?

Comment: What should `yourmatch(c("apple", "banana","pear"), list)` return?

Comment: I suggest that you don't name anything `list` (since this already exists).

Answer (score 2):

You asked *"Is there a "match exist" statement in R?"*. Yes: `is.element` (or more common in R, `%in%`).

```
which(is.element(c("apple", "banana"), list))
# [1] 1
```

You might need to swap the first and second elements depending on the result you want. For example, using @Codoremifa's question in the comments, compare:

```
> which(is.element(list, c("apple", "banana","pear")))
[1] 1 2
> which(is.element(c("apple", "banana","pear"), list))
[1] 1 3
```

The same applies for @Spacedman's answer, but the order is reversed.

Answer (score 1):

Howabout just stripping out the NAs?

```
> na.omit(match(c("apple", "banana"), list) )
[1] 1
attr(,"na.action")
[1] 2
attr(,"class")
[1] "exclude"
```

ignoring the attributes, that's just a vector of 1.